# Performance Testing Jmeter

Tags: javascript, while-loop, conditional-statements, jmeter, performance-testing

```
${__javaScript("${response}".indexOf("string") == -1,)}
```

Am using the above while controller expression in my script as a first condition by extracting the response value and string, where  Here I need to add another response value where the string value will change. used the below condition but it is not working

```
${__javaScript("${Resp}".indexOf("End of Cart !!") == -1,)}|| 
${__javaScript("${Resp2}".indexOf("") ==-1,)}
```

Please let me know the condition, that satisfies two conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can combine 2 conditions in one expression, something like:

```
${__javaScript(("${Resp}".indexOf("End of Cart !!") == -1 && "${Resp2}".indexOf("") == -1),)}
```

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)

You might also want to consider migrating to [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function as Nashorn engine was removed in [JDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you won't be able to use __javaScript() function on newer Java versions.